# Insert spaceing between chaptername and thechapter in header

Tags: latex

I am using the scrheadings package in Latex. I want to add the chapter name and number with the following command to my header:

```
\ihead[\chaptername \thechapter]{}
```

The output looks like "Chapter1". I would like to have a 'normal' space between the chaptername and the number like "Chapter 1". What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\ihead[\chaptername{} \thechapter]{}
```

to ensure that the macro does not shallow the space following it

Comment: Thank you this works.

Comment: @MCK1886 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Probably add an `~` for your spacing...:

```latex
\ihead[\chaptername~\thechapter]{}
```